# My website text layout gets flipped when I use any symbol?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I just downloaded a template recently to use for a website but as I just copied Html from the template into my project so I could integrate my backend into it. the website layout almost got flipped 360 deg.

Lemme show you what I mean 
This is a from from that template

[image]

But when i include it in my own project it shows me like this

[image]

Not only this form Everything is flipped almost like navbar is flipped too but some are fine!

Comment: can you add the code?  that would help in addressing your issue.

Comment: anything you are missing to add

Comment: I don't think I can add the code because it's too much I mean toooooooo much so it would be a dumb mistake to add code.I want some general suggestions that anybody can intuitively guess about what's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing code I think somewhere in the parent you have

```
flex-direction: row-reverse;
text-align: right;
```

you need to check that and remove that code and your form is good

see working example of your problem https://jsfiddle.net/wb41Lgjv/